# Flutter calendar_view library custom startHour in dayview or weekview

Tags: flutter, calendarview, pub.dev

Flutter calendar_view library custom hour in dayview or weekview

https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_view

how to customize startHour is '08:00'.
default startHour is '01:00', endHour is '23:00'

i want customizing startHour: '09:00', endHour: '18:00'

Answer (score 0):

I think custom start hour is not supported yet in calendar_view.
you can use another package -> syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^20.3.50

In syncfusion calendar there's an option to use custom start and end. hour.

```
        timeSlotViewSettings:
        const TimeSlotViewSettings(startHour: 9, endHour: 18),
```